# What does an English Liberty-shaded lamp look like?

Tags: world-war-one, england

[The London Venture](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/40375/40375-h/40375-h.htm) by Michael Arlen several times mentions a woman with dark hair given a blue sheen as she sits under a Liberty-shaded lamp. Any idea what this lamp looked like?

Illustrator: Michel Sevier
Copyright, 1920, By George H. Doran Company

Comment: A Liberty-shaded lamp is a lamp with a blue lampshade sold by [Libertys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_(department_store)), an up-market department store. So it's not a particular design of lamp but one of a range of designs.

Comment: @KillingTime you should make this into an answer